# Field not injected in Android Dagger project

Tags: java, android, dagger

I am playing with Dagger on Android. I created a model `UserPreference`, a module called `PreferenceModule` and another class `UserPreferenceTest` which is a test of the `PreferenceModule`. I have below 3 java files

UserPreference.java

```
package com.sigicn.preference;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.sigicn.commonmodels.Application;

public class UserPreference {
    public String name, weiboAccount;

    @Inject
    public Application[] frequentlyUsedApps;
}
```

Then PreferenceModule.java

```
package com.sigicn.preference;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import com.sigicn.commonmodels.Application;
import com.sigicn.utils.MiscUtils;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module(library = true, complete = true)
public class PreferenceModule {

    @Provides @Singleton UserPreference provideUserPreference() {
        UserPreference userPreference = new UserPreference();
        userPreference.frequentlyUsedApps = provideApplications();
        return userPreference;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton Application[] provideApplications() {
        return new Application[]{
                new Application(
                        MiscUtils.generateUUID(), "Youtube"),
                new Application(
                        MiscUtils.generateUUID(), "Pixi")
            };
    }

}
```

Then UserPreferenceTest.java

```
package com.sigicn.test.preference;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.sigicn.preference.PreferenceModule;
import com.sigicn.preference.UserPreference;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.ObjectGraph;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

public class UserPreferenceTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    @Module(injects = {UserPreference.class, UserPreferenceTest.class}, 
            includes = PreferenceModule.class)
    static class TestModule {
    }

    ObjectGraph objectGraph; 

    @Inject
    UserPreference userPreference;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        if (objectGraph == null) {
            objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new TestModule());
        }
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void testFrequentlyUsedApps()
    { 
        UserPreference localUserPreference = objectGraph.get(UserPreference.class);
        assertNotNull(localUserPreference);
        assertEquals(localUserPreference.frequentlyUsedApps.length, 2);

        objectGraph.inject(this);
        assertNotNull(userPreference);
        assertEquals(userPreference.frequentlyUsedApps.length, 2);
        assertSame(localUserPreference, userPreference);
        assertSame(localUserPreference.frequentlyUsedApps, userPreference.frequentlyUsedApps);
    }
}
```

But don't know why, that the `frequentlyUsedApps` of `UserPreference` is not injected as expected. Any idea why?

**Update:**

I think I have figured out the reason. It's because that I manually create `UserPreference` and use it in the provider. If I remove the Provider for `UserPreference`, and let *Dagger* to wire it automatically, then the field `frequentlyUsedApps` does get injected. So it is my fault of not understanding *Dagger* well.

Comment: did you set the Annotation Processors in the IDE? Although I am guessing you did, but you can never be too sure.

Comment: I did. That's why objectGraph can be created successfully. It's just that I am not able to let the objectGraph automatically inject member of UserPreference. I am guessing the reason is that I am using UserPreference both as an target of injection and source of provider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to add some ObjectGraph#inject calls.

In each class where you have an @Inject annotation, you will also need a call to the inject method of the ObjectGraph you created.

I have had been struggling with this for a while also.  I think the basic pattern is:

1. Annotate your fields to indicate you want to inject them
2. Create a module to "provide" the instances for those @Injects
3. Create the graph somewhere (seems like most people are doing that in
   the Application class)
4. In the classes you want to inject stuff from your module, get an
   instance of the graph and call inject(this).

I started using a singleton rather than the Application class, because at least for now I have some places were I want to inject the app itself.

So here is what I am currently doing, which seems to work pretty weill

```
public class Injector {

    private static Injector mInjector;
    private ObjectGraph mObjectGraph;
    private MyApp mApp;

    private Injector() {

    }

    public static Injector getInstance() {
        if (mInjector == null) {
            mInjector = new Injector();
        }
        return mInjector;
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                                new ApplicationModule(mApp),
                                new AndroidModule(mApp)
                             );
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        getObjectGraph().inject(object);
    }

    public ObjectGraph getObjectGraph() {
        return mObjectGraph;
    }

    public void initialize(MyApp app) {
        mApp = app;
        mObjectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());  
        System.out.println(String.format("init object graph = %s",mObjectGraph.toString()));

    }

}
```

Then in my application class I have a constructor like this:

```
public MyApp() {
    System.out.println("myapp construtor");  
    Injector.getInstance().initialize(this);
    Injector.getInstance().inject(this);

}
```

Then when I want to inject something I do this

```
@Inject Bus mBus;

public GcmBroadcastReceiver() {
    Injector.getInstance().inject(this);

}
```

I have two modules , one for production and one for test

The production one has this

```
@Provides @Singleton
public Bus provideBus () {
    return BusProvider.getInstance();
}
```

and the test one has this

```
@Provides @Singleton
public Bus provideBus () {
    return mock(Bus.class);
}
```

Comment: Although that's indeed the case, I kinda think it defeat the whole purpose of auto-wiring. In my opinion, it should auto wire itself instead of requiring user to inject every object and its member.